# How to Combine Arc with Draw in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a combination of rectangle with arc on the right side, to produce this:

[image: a]

All I can produce is this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,x=1cm,y=0.8cm]
        
        \draw[-, thin] (0, 0) -- (4.6, 0)  arc[start angle=0, end
        angle=60, radius=6.6] -- (1.2,5.7) -- (0, 5.7) -- cycle;
        
        
        \draw[<->] (-0.2,0) -- (-0.2,5.7) node[left, midway]  {\footnotesize $40$};
        \draw[<->] (0,-0.5) -- (2,-0.5) node[below, midway]  {\footnotesize $8$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I prefer to use `/draw` and Tikz.

Comment: Is it necesarry that it is an arc, i.e. a segment of a circle? Otherwise I'd just use `\draw (0, 0) -- (2, 0) to[out=70, in=-60] +(-1, 5.7) -| cycle;`.

Comment: There is another option better than arc then. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `plot` the points with option `smooth` to get a smooth(ish) curve that has the correct proportional lengths. You can also adjust the `tension` of the curve.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\colorlet{fillcolor}{cyan!30}

\tikzset{bararrow/.style={{Bar[width=4mm]<}-{>Bar[width=4mm]}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.25, >=latex, font=\small]
  \draw[thick, smooth, cyan, fill=fillcolor](0,0)-- plot coordinates {(8,0)(10,1)(10.5,2)(10.5,3)(10,4)(9,5)(8,6)(6.5,7)(5,8)}-|cycle;
  \foreach \x[count=\y] in {10,10.5,10.5,10,9,8,6.5}
    \draw[<->](0,\y)--node[fill=fillcolor]{\x}(\x,\y);
  \draw[bararrow, yshift=-3mm](0,0)--node[fill=white]{8}(8,0);
  \draw[bararrow, yshift=3mm](0,8)--node[fill=white]{5}(5,8);
  \draw[bararrow, xshift=-12mm](0,0)--node[fill=white]{40}(0,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use a very barbaric way, yours is better and more proportional

Answer (score 5):

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, intersections, quotes}
\tikzset{
  dim line distance/.initial=.2cm,
  dim line style/.style={<->},
  dim line delim/.style={-, shorten <=2\pgflinewidth, shorten >=-7\pgflinewidth},
  dim line text/.style={midway, auto=left, font=\footnotesize},
  pics/dim line/.style args={#1--#2}{code={
    \draw[dim line style]
      ($(#1)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dim line distance}!90:(#2)$) coordinate (@1)
      to node[dim line text,style/.expand once=\tikzpictextoptions]{$\tikzpictext$}
      ($(#2)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dim line distance}!-90:(#1)$)coordinate (@2);
    \draw[dim line delim] (#1) to (@1);
    \draw[dim line delim] (#2) to (@2);}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[> = Latex, x = .2cm, y = 0.1cm]

\draw[draw=blue,fill=blue!50, name path=area]
                        (0, 0) coordinate (bl)
                  -- (right:8) coordinate (br)
  to[out=70, in=-60] +(-3, 40) coordinate (tr)
                            -| coordinate (tl) cycle;

\pic ["40"] {dim line=bl--tl}
 pic [ "8"] {dim line=br--bl}
 pic [ "5"] {dim line=tl--tr};

\foreach \level in {1, ..., 7} {
  \path[overlay, help lines, name path=hor\level]
    (10pt, \level/8*40) -- +(right:10);
  \draw[name intersections={of=area and hor\level, by=is-\level},
    <->, nodes={fill=blue!50, node font=\footnotesize},
    /pgf/number format/.cd, fixed zerofill, precision=1]
    let \p 0 = ($(is-\level) - (0,0)$),
        \p B = ($(br)        - (bl) $), % redundant
        \n 0 = {scalar(\x0/\x B*8)} in  % scalar removes units
    (0, \level/8*40) -- node {$\pgfmathprintnumber{\n0}$} (is-\level);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]