# Create Irregular Shape for Lamina Proportionally

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw this very irregular shape

[image: 1]

I have this MWE from this : [How to Combine Arc with Draw in Tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674910/how-to-combine-arc-with-draw-in-tikz?noredirect=1#comment1676633_674910)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\colorlet{fillcolor}{cyan!30}

\tikzset{bararrow/.style={{Bar[width=4mm]<}-{>Bar[width=4mm]}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.25, >=latex, font=\small]
  \draw[thick, smooth, cyan, fill=fillcolor](0,0)-- plot coordinates {(8,0)(10,1)(10.5,2)(10.5,3)(10,4)(9,5)(8,6)(6.5,7)(5,8)}-|cycle;
  \foreach \x[count=\y] in {10,10.5,10.5,10,9,8,6.5}
    \draw[<->](0,\y)--node[fill=fillcolor]{\x}(\x,\y);
  \draw[bararrow, yshift=-3mm](0,0)--node[fill=white]{8}(8,0);
  \draw[bararrow, yshift=3mm](0,8)--node[fill=white]{5}(5,8);
  \draw[bararrow, xshift=-12mm](0,0)--node[fill=white]{40}(0,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there any other better way with Tikz to create the shape above? We need to take notice of the irregularity at the left and right side of this lamina. It is Illinois map.

Comment: You could do something similar as in this [Q656268](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/656268/): Find the shape of the state in Vector format and convert it to TikZ somehow. Or you just trace the outline manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file [`Map_of_USA_without_state_names.svg`](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Map_of_USA_without_state_names.svg)<sup>[GFDL](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en) and [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/deed.en)</sup>, made by users Wapcaplet, Angr, Mahagaja and Techman224, contains the outline of Illinois in a vector format.
which we can simply extract from the source file.
It only consists of straight segments, though.

Once extracted, the path for Illinois can be included in TikZ via the `svg.path` library,
this is basically the same procedure as in
[Regional map of Namibia on tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/656268/16595).

To reference the corners of the outline, I'll setup a `show path construction`
decoration to declare a coordinate for every point on the path.

The rotation of −3.5 is found manually to rotate the map so that the north border is relatively horizontal.

I've added a second image that shows the corners with their number labeled.
This is done by the commented loop.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta,
  calc,
  svg.path,
  intersections,
  quotes,
  decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{
  insert svg/.style={yscale=-1,insert path={\pgfextra\pgfpathsvg{#1}\endpgfextra}},
  Illinois/.style={insert svg={M 189.27300,98.386000 L 189.27300,97.251000 L 189.42300,95.872000 L 190.11100,94.983000 L 190.65400,93.801000 L 191.44100,92.521000 L 191.29500,90.748000 L 190.75400,89.910000 L 190.65400,88.925000 L 190.90000,87.250000 L 190.75400,85.131000 L 190.35800,80.253000 L 189.96500,75.573000 L 189.71900,72.024000 L 189.32300,71.779000 L 189.07700,70.991000 L 188.68400,69.856000 L 188.19000,69.315000 L 187.74700,68.526000 L 187.67700,66.855000 L 184.65900,67.253000 L 176.36800,67.776000 L 173.72000,67.646000 L 173.78800,68.368000 L 174.48500,68.577000 L 174.76400,68.925000 L 174.90300,69.483000 L 176.08700,70.529000 L 176.29600,71.225000 L 176.08700,72.270000 L 175.53000,73.386000 L 175.32300,74.151000 L 174.62600,74.711000 L 174.06700,74.919000 L 172.46500,75.336000 L 172.25400,75.896000 L 172.04700,76.521000 L 172.25400,76.940000 L 172.81300,77.428000 L 172.74300,78.684000 L 172.18600,79.169000 L 171.97700,79.657000 L 171.97700,80.493000 L 171.42000,80.633000 L 170.93200,80.982000 L 170.86200,81.400000 L 170.93200,82.027000 L 170.40900,82.427000 L 170.09700,83.280000 L 170.23600,84.396000 L 170.93300,86.625000 L 173.16200,88.926000 L 174.83600,90.039000 L 174.76600,91.364000 L 175.04500,91.782000 L 176.99400,91.920000 L 177.83200,92.339000 L 177.62300,93.454000 L 176.92600,95.266000 L 176.71700,96.243000 L 177.41200,97.427000 L 179.36500,99.031000 L 180.75800,99.238000 L 181.38500,100.77100 L 182.01200,101.74800 L 181.73500,102.65400 L 182.22300,103.90800 L 182.77800,104.53500 L 183.68200,104.43100 L 183.85800,103.80600 L 184.54700,103.26500 L 185.18800,103.06800 L 186.02600,103.46300 L 187.11000,103.85800 L 187.45400,103.75800 L 187.50300,103.06900 L 187.11000,102.33100 L 187.20800,101.64000 L 187.80000,101.19700 L 188.58700,101.00200 L 189.07900,100.80500 L 188.83300,100.26200 L 188.63800,99.670000 L 188.98200,99.426000 L 189.27300,98.386000 z}}
}
\tikzset{
  mark points/.style args={#1from#2named #3}{
    decorate, /utils/exec=\gdef#1{#2}, decoration={show path construction,
      moveto code={\xdef#1{\pgfinteval{#1+1}}%
        \pgfcoordinate{#3-#1}{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentfirst}},
      lineto code={\xdef#1{\pgfinteval{#1+1}}%
        \pgfcoordinate{#3-#1}{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}}}},
  dim line distance/.initial=.2cm,
  dim line style/.style={<->},
  dim line delim/.style={-,shorten <=2\pgflinewidth,shorten >=-7\pgflinewidth},
  dim line text/.style={midway,auto=left,font=\footnotesize},
  pics/@dim line/.style n args={4}{code={\draw[dim line style]
    ($(#1)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dim line distance}!90:(#2)$) coordinate(@1) to
    node[dim line text,style/.expand once=\tikzpictextoptions]{$\tikzpictext$}
    ($(#2)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dim line distance}!-90:(#1)$)coordinate(@2);
    \draw[dim line delim] (#3) to (@1); \draw[dim line delim] (#4) to (@2);}},
  pics/dim line/.style args={#1--#2}{@dim line={#1}{#2}{#1}{#2}},
  pics/dim line vertical/.style args=  {#1--#2 through #3}{
    @dim line={{#1}-|{#3}}{{#2}-|{#3}}{#1}{#2}},
  pics/dim line horizontal/.style args={#1--#2 through #3}{
    @dim line={{#1}|-{#3}}{{#2}|-{#3}}{#1}{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5, > = {Latex[scale=.7]}]
\draw[local bounding box=illinois, blue,
  fill=blue!20, rotate=-3.5, Illinois, name path = illinois,
  postaction={mark points=\illinoisCorners from -1 named illinois}];

\foreach[count=\i] \n in {58,  79,  95, 124, 137, 155, 167, 170, 191,
                         206, 212, 209, 192, 179, 184, 151, 139, 132}{
  \path[overlay] ($(illinois.south west)!\i/19!(illinois.north west)$)
    -- ++(right:5) [name path=hor];
  \path[name intersections={of=illinois and hor}]
    node[node font=\footnotesize]
      at ([xshift=1mm]intersection-1-|illinois.south) (node) {\n};
  \draw[->] (node) edge (intersection-1) edge (intersection-2);
}
% \foreach \i in {1,...,\illinoisCorners} \node[fill=white, fill opacity=.5,
%   text opacity=1, inner sep=0pt] at (illinois-\i) {\tiny\i};
\pic ["380"] {dim line vertical  =
  illinois-19--illinois-67 through illinois.east}
 pic ["140"] {dim line horizontal=
  illinois-22--illinois-19 through illinois.north};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image][image]

Comment: Took me a long time, this one is really difficult. Thanks a lot.

Comment: is this context, what is `dim line` ?

Comment: @anis See the end of the example. It's a `pic` that places the dimension lines parallel to the line specified by its argument offset by `dim line distance`. The `dim line horizontal` and `dim line vertical` use a third point which specifies the *y* or *x* value to what this distance should be measured against. This allows very easily to draw these dimension lines with exaggerated orthogonal bars. This makes them somewhat similar to the typical CAD dimension lines, I hope.