# In TikZ, is there a (convenient) way to draw two arrow heads pointing inward with two vertical bars and whitespace between (see sketch)?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows

In the `tikzpicture` environment, it is simple to create a double-ended arrow with two vertical bars. See the sketch below.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[|<->|] (-2, 0)--(2, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to create something with arrow heads pointing "outside-in" with whitespace between the two vertical bars like in the sketch below?

[image]

This is commonly done in physics diagrams when a length is too small to be indicated in the first way.

Do I have to manually place these bars and arrow heads, or is there a better way? Any comments or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: like this? `\draw[>|-|<] (0, -2)--(0, 2);
 \draw[white,shorten <=2.1pt,shorten >=2.1pt] (0, -2)--(0, 2);`

Comment: @BlackMild Yes. This is very close. Two minor issues: (1) I accidentally mixed up the x and y coords in the OP so I edited my post. (2) we have to offset the coords slightly because changing `|<->|` to `>|-|<` displaces the vertical bars slightly.

Comment: How should the vertical bar line up in regards to the specified start and end of the line? See [Q111051](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111051)

Answer (score 9):

Instead of guesstimating the shortening of the line or specifying a `sep` depending on arrow tip sizes that aren't easy to find out unless you specify them yourself, for the inverted tips I'd place the arrow tips at the start and at the end.

Though, no one wants to place them manually so I suggest the `UnMeasure` and `UnMeasure'` styles that use `edge node`s. This will need you to use `to` instead of `--`.

---

Note the difference between `Measure` and `Measure'` where the Bar actually is placed on the target points instead of [just touching it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111051). Instead of a negative `sep`, one could also load the `ext.arrows` library and use `Untipped Bar`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  pics/arrow/.style={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    code=\pgfarrowdraw{#1}}, pics/arrow/.default=>,
  Measure/.tip ={Straight Barb[] . Bar[             ]},
  Measure'/.tip={Straight Barb[] . Bar[sep=+0pt +-.5]},
  Measure/.style ={Measure -Measure },
  Measure'/.style={Measure'-Measure'},
  UnMeasure/.style={
    line to, draw=none, arrows=-, % force -- in to, disable drawing and no tips
    every to/.append style={edge node={pic[at start]          {arrow=Measure}
                                       pic[at end, xscale=-1] {arrow=Measure}}}},
  UnMeasure'/.style={
    line to, draw=none, arrows=-, % force -- in to, disable drawing and no tips
    every to/.append style={edge node={pic[at start]          {arrow=Measure'}
                                       pic[at end, xscale=-1] {arrow=Measure'}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
\draw[help lines] (-.5,-.5) grid[ystep=.5] (1.5,1.9);
\draw[  Measure ] ( 0, 0  ) -- (1, 0  );
\draw[  Measure'] ( 0,  .5) -- (1,  .5);
\draw[UnMeasure ] ( 0, 1  ) to (1, 1  );
\draw[UnMeasure'] ( 0, 1.5) to (1, 1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

The second image is achieved by using `Straight Barb[angle'=60]`.

[image] [image]

Comment: I really feel like none of the answers to this post fulfill the "convenient" requirement. is there room for a Tikz library or package to do that, I wonder?

Comment: @anis, what is "convenient" for you? New library for such unusual and very rear demand?

Comment: @anis Arrow tips are more complicated than they seem (and these are some easy ones), the length of the Straight Barb changes with the angle because of the line join. We could define new tips that “overtip” the line end but the same lengths that define where the tip is drawn is used to place another one behind it, it will get tricky when combining two tips. Depending on how OP wants to use this, I'd package that in a macro or a pic (see [`dim line`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/675018)) that does the work without the user having to think about using `to`.

Comment: @Zarko it's a fairly common way to indicate small dimensions in drawings, where the more common double headed arrow with bars won't fit.  Of course that might not make it common enough to include in a library

Comment: @ChrisH, yes what you say, but this is ate technical drawing (at least in time when I learn it in school) done on different way. Not just draw arrows heads ...

Comment: @Zarko in true engineering drawing, yes (and for that I'd use a CAD package anyway).  Some ideas from that carry over to detailed, dimensioned, diagrams, which is what I guess the OP is doing.

Comment: To OP and @anis: How more convenient can it get? Yes, a proper arrow tip thingy would be nice but I think this is the next best option.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel you clearly answered my question. I find your approach convenient enough. I understand that creating a package for the tikz style is pointless. I was just wondering why it is always complicated to manipulate  arrows. it is among the most verbose concepts of Tikz, to me.

Answer (score 7):

This exploits that the arrows reset the dash pattern. This allows one to make the line between the arrow heads disappear. In addition, one can reverse the arrow heads of the `arrows.meta` library easily.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[{Straight Barb[reversed].Bar[]}-{Bar[].Straight Barb[reversed]},dash pattern=on 0pt off 500pt]
    (-2, 0)--(2, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously you can change the appearance of the arrow heads, make this as style, and so on.

Comment: Instead of a cheaty dash pattern you can use `\path`/`draw=none` but [`tips=true`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#pgf/tips).

Comment: It is always a great idea to use a method that requires two keys when one needs only one.

Answer (score 6):

With `arrows.meta`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
  \tikz{
    \draw[help lines](0,-1)grid(4,2);
    \draw [{Stealth[length=4pt]}-{Stealth[length=4pt]}] (0,1) -- (4,1);
    \draw [draw=none,tips=true,{Stealth[length=4pt,reversed]}-{Stealth[length=4pt,reversed]},shorten <=-4pt,shorten >=-4pt] (0,0) -- (4,0);
  }
\end{document}
```

EDIT: with the Chris H.'s comment, but a much less successful solution than that of Qrrbrbirlbel. In particular the `shorten >=-3pt`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  mytips/.tip = {Straight Barb[length=2pt]},
  mytipsrev /.tip = {Straight Barb[length=2pt,reversed]},
  myarrow/.style = {{mytips}-{mytips}},
  myarrowreverse/.style = {draw=none,tips=true,{mytipsrev}|-|{mytipsrev},shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines](0,-1)grid(4,2);
    \draw [myarrow] (0,1) -- (4,1);
    \draw [myarrowreverse] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: with `arrows.meta` can't you double up and use an arrow-shaped arrowhead as well as a `bar` to get the line the OP has sketched as well?  I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: @Chris H, I edited my answer (it's far from perfect).

Answer (score 4):

Oh, we should not write a new library for such trivial task!

There is a simple way with plain TikZ, that is, using suitable `pic`s (small picture on paths). The option `sloped` is necessary, and

```
pic[sloped,pos=0]{tipL} pic[sloped,pos=1]{tipR}
```

works as desired.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[tipR/.pic={\draw (45:.2)--(0,0)--(-45:.2) (0,.2)--(0,-.2);},
 tipL/.pic={\draw (135:.2)--(0,0)--(-135:.2) (0,.2)--(0,-.2);}
]
\path       (0,0)--(2,0)  pic[sloped,pos=0]{tipL} pic[sloped,pos=1]{tipR};
\path[red]  (3,-1)--(3,1) pic[sloped,pos=0]{tipL} pic[sloped,pos=1]{tipR};
\path[blue] (4,0)--+(2,2) pic[sloped,pos=0]{tipL} pic[sloped,pos=1]{tipR};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**PS:** To make the tip of arrows just touching the bars, we may use  `xshift=-\pgflinewidth`

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
tipR/.pic={\draw[xshift={\pgflinewidth}] (45:.2)--(0,0)--(-45:.2); 
           \draw (0,.2)--(0,-.2);},
tipL/.pic={\draw[xshift={-\pgflinewidth}] (135:.2)--(0,0)--(-135:.2);
           \draw (0,.2)--(0,-.2);}
}

\draw[gray!30] (-1,-2) grid (7,3);
\def\mypictip{pic[sloped,pos=0]{tipL} pic[sloped,pos=1]{tipR}}


\path[line width=2pt] (0,0)--(2,0) \mypictip;
\path[red,very thick] (3,-1)--(3,1) \mypictip;
\path[blue,line width=1pt] (4,0)--+(2,1) \mypictip;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

My attempt so far as been to write the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->|] (-2.01, 0)--(-2, 0);
    \draw[->|] (2.01, 0)--(2, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Alternatively, Black Mild in the comments suggested

```
\draw[>|-|<] (-2, 0)--(2, 0);   
\draw[white,shorten <=2.1pt,shorten >=2.1pt] (-2, 0)--(2, 0);
```

However, this second suggestion would require you to manually adjust the positions of the arrow tips since the vertical bars will be displaced when you change from `>|-|<` to `|<->|`. Nonetheless this is still an interesting suggestion that I think can be helpful.